# get_option return incorrect values

Tags: plugins, php, options

I'm making a Wordpress Plugin, and I'm starting with the Admin Settings page, I have the page setup and in the menu bar, i have also added sections and fields in to the page and they all work fine, when i change values of the fields and save the page and refresh the settings are the same, which tells me they are being saved. Correct?!

Now, when i try to call the settings, i cannot get a proper value! On the settings page i have 1 checkbox and one text field, i cannot get the value for either one!

The code i am using to get the value is this:

```
<?php
if(get_option( 'main_dashboard_check' ) ? get_option( 'main_dashboard_check' ) : 'no'){echo 'yes';}else{echo 'no';};
?>
```

When i use this for either field, i get the same value:

`var_dump(get_option('main_text'));` This shows 'bool(false)' for both the checkbox and the text field.

On the admin page, here are the fields:

```
<?php
function admin_init() {

register_setting( $this->settings_field, $this->settings_field, array($this, 'sanitize_theme_options') );
add_option( $this->settings_field, Media_Press_Settings::$default_settings );

add_settings_section('mediapress_main', '',  
array($this, 'main_section_text'), 'main_settings_page');

add_settings_field('main_text', 'Main Text', 
array($this, 'render_main_text'), 'main_settings_page', 'mediapress_main');

add_settings_field('main_dashboard_check', 'Title', 
array($this, 'render_main_checkbox'), 'main_settings_page', 'mediapress_main', 
array('id' => 'main_dashboard_check', 'value' => 'yes', 'text' => 'Test Checkbox') );

}

function render_main_checkbox($args) {
$id = 'mediapress_options['.$args['id'].']';
?>
<input name="<?php echo $id;?>" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $args['value'];?>" <?php echo isset($this->options[$args['id']]) ? 'checked' : '';?> /> <?php echo " {$args['text']}"; ?>
<?php 
}
?>
```

So thats some of the code rendering the admin page, its the checkbox and text field, when i try to get the value for either one, nothing happens, this is the code I'm using to get the value

```
<?php
if(get_option( 'main_dashboard_check' ) ? get_option( 'main_dashboard_check' ) : 'yes'){echo 'yes';}else{echo 'no';};
?>
```

Nothing happens! Its always printing out the text 'no'. A var dump just shows **bool(false)**

Can anyone help me? Would really appreciated

Many thanks and sorry if i sound dumb, I'm new to PHP!

Comment: If the value of `main_dashboard_check` is really stored in the `wp_options` table, you should be able to see its value with `select * from wp_options where option_name like '%main_dashboard_check%';`
Can you first check that it is indeed the case?
When `get_option` return `false` it means that the option cannot be found (or that the value is really `false`).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the get_option() function like this:

```
<?php

$main_dashboard_check = get_option( 'main_dashboard_check' );
var_dump( $main_dashboard_check ); /* outputs false if the value does not exist */

$main_dashboard_check = get_option( 'main_dashboard_check', 'default_value' );
var_dump( $main_dashboard_check ); /* outputs 'default_value' if the value does not exist */

?>
```

Comment: Thank you but this still outputs 'bool(false)'.. Anything I do its the same result!!! I can't figure it out, if the checkbox is being rendered on the settings page AND its settings are being saved, why is it not retrieving that info!!!! If I use the 2nd code you gave (with the default value), I get the following: 'string(13) "default_value"' and changing the checkbox value doesn't change this!!